# Proper way to create a "show" page that allows me to update an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following controller

```
class ProductController < ApplicationController

  def show
    id = params[:id]
    @product = Product.find(id)
  end

  def update
    render text:params
  end
end
```

When I visit `/product/1` I would show a page with product 1's details, and a way to update them. This is what I've done for the view:

```
<%= form_for @product, url: {:action => :update} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field "name" %></br>
  <%= f.text_field "quantity" %></br>
  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

When I hit update, it will render the request

`{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"sRzyQ0nP2ycWwgaS9eu5vHcID1b+hIl5Vho3KfX3XuE=", "product"=>{"name"=>"Test Name", "quantity"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Update", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"product", "id"=>"1"}`

I would modify my `update` method to save the new attributes and redirect the user back to the `show` page.

Is this how I should be updating database objects?

Comment: Yes, that is a very typical scenario in a rails app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you have to:

```
  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
      redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'show'
    end
  end
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

The Rails way is instead of a `show` action to render the form, use a `edit` action. Take a look to the scaffold: `rails g scaffold foo` to understand how Rails works.

But seems that what you want is a In-place-editing. Watch [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing) Railscasts.